# Debian cdrom has unsigned repository

Tags: debian

I installed debian from an usb stick on an offline computer. After booting
apt-get does not recognize the usb stick as the former cdrom. I manually
mounted the stick, and added the line below to `sources.list`:

```
deb file:/media/installdisk/ ....
```

Now apt-get complains that the repository is unsigned. Why does debian not
sign their repositories on their cdrom isos? 
Does that mean the installer blindly trusted the packages in repository 
on the usb stick during the installation?

Is there a way to use "deb cdrom: ..." together with an already
mounted device? Apt-get seems to just unmount my usb stick and
ask for the CD.

I am unwilling to do :

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/ ...
```

as I do want the files on the usb stick to be verified by apt.

Comment: Can I safely use a cdrom from "a friend" to install packages on a previously installed system, or do I need to check the signature of the cd?